# Recyclerview not show data

Tags: java, android, xml

My recyclerview not show any data from firebase. I don't see any errors so I don't know why. I followed the FirebaseUI guide from a stackoverflow member. but still didn't work. I use android 3.0.1. Sorry if my code so bad. I'm little bit mad cause of this case

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean isOpen = false;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FloatingActionButton fab_plus, fab_logout, fab_create, fab_editacc;
    private Animation fabOpen, fabClose, fabRClockwise, fabRantiClockwise;
    private RecyclerView recyclerviewku;
    private DatabaseReference myDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser CUser;
    private Query query;
    private List<Journal> list;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fab_plus = findViewById(R.id.fab_plus);
        fab_logout = findViewById(R.id.fab_logout);
        fab_create = findViewById(R.id.fab_create);
        fab_editacc = findViewById(R.id.fab_editacc);

        fabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
        fabRClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
        fabRantiClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);



        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        recyclerviewku = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.journal_list);
        recyclerviewku.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerviewku.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("journal");


        //get current user
        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    // user auth state is changed - user is null
                    // launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isOpen) {
                    fab_create.startAnimation(fabClose);
                    fab_logout.startAnimation(fabClose);
                    fab_editacc.startAnimation(fabClose);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(fabRantiClockwise);
                    fab_create.setClickable(false);
                    fab_logout.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;
                } else {
                    fab_create.startAnimation(fabOpen);
                    fab_logout.startAnimation(fabOpen);
                    fab_editacc.startAnimation(fabOpen);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(fabRClockwise);
                    fab_create.setClickable(true);
                    fab_logout.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;
                }
            }
        });
        fab_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signOut();
            }
        });
        fab_create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class JournalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

        public JournalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView = mView;
        }

        public void setActivity(String activity) {
            TextView title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.journal_title);
            title.setText(activity);
        }

        public void setStart(String start) {
            TextView mulai = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.journal_timestart);
            mulai.setText(start);
        }

        public void setEnd(String end) {
            TextView akhir = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.journal_timeend);
            akhir.setText(end);
        }
    }

    public void signOut() {
        auth.signOut();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("journal");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Journal> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Journal>()
                        .setQuery(query, Journal.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Journal, JournalViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public JournalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.journal_row, parent, false);

                return new JournalViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(JournalViewHolder holder, int position, Journal model) {
                holder.setActivity(model.getActivity());
                holder.setStart(model.getStart());
                holder.setEnd(model.getEnd());
            }

        };
        recyclerviewku.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (authListener != null) {
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
        }
    }
}
```

**Journal.java**

```
    public class Journal {
    private String codejob;
    private String category;
    private String codecategory;
    private String activity;
    private String description;
    private String sapsomp;
    private String month;
    private String start;
    private String end;
    private String hours;
    private String venue;
    private String vendor;
    private String unittype;
    private String remark;

    public Journal(){}
    public Journal(String codejob, String codecategory, String category, String activity, String description, String sapsomp, String month, String start, String end, String hours, String venue, String vendor, String unittype, String remark){
        this.codejob = codejob;
        this.category = category;
        this.codecategory = codecategory;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.description = description;
        this.sapsomp = sapsomp;
        this.month = month;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.venue = venue;
        this.vendor = vendor;
        this.unittype = unittype;
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    public String getCodejob(){
        return codejob;
    }

    public void setCodejob(String codejob){
        this.codejob = this.codejob;
    }

    public String getCategory(){
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category){
        this.category = this.category;
    }

    public String getCodecategory(){
        return codecategory;
    }

    public void setCodecategory(String codecategory){
        this.codecategory = codecategory;
    }

    public String getActivity(){
        return activity;
    }

    public void setActivity(String activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getSapsomp(){
        return sapsomp;
    }

    public void setSapsomp(String sapsomp){
        this.sapsomp = sapsomp;
    }

    public String getMonth(){
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month){
        this.month = month;
    }

    public String getStart(){
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start){
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getEnd(){
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(String end){
        this.end = end;
    }

    public String getHours(){
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(String hours){
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public String getVenue(){
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(String venue){
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    public String getVendor(){
        return vendor;
    }

    public void setVendor(String vendor){
        this.vendor = vendor;
    }

    public String getUnittype(){
        return unittype;
    }

    public void setUnittype(String unittype){
        this.unittype = unittype;
    }

    public String getRemark(){
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark){
        this.remark = remark;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="id.sch.smktelkom_mlg.pw.utjournal.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="245dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_header"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/pprofile"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        app:civ_border_color="#fff"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Aska Ivan"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="80111315"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                                android:text="Branch"
                                android:textColor="#4a4a4a" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                                android:text="Area"
                                android:textColor="#4a4a4a" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                                android:text="BLP"
                                android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
                                android:textSize="18dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                                android:text="TTA BALIKPAPAN"
                                android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
                                android:textSize="18dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/journal_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fab1"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_editacc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fab3"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fab2"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:tint="#fff"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**journal_row.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"enter code here
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/journal_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Judul Journal"
                android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/journal_timestart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="1/12/2018"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text=" to "
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/journal_timeend"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="1/13/2018"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Did you debug to see if you are getting data from firebase?

Comment: @Napster yes I did. But still didn't work

Comment: @AskaIvan have checked that ur list is not empty after fetching data from firebase?

Comment: I think u r attaching data with recyclerview before u get it from firebase

Comment: First check if you are getting data from the journal endpoint. If you are, then try to put the `FirebaseAdapter` code in `onCreate` instead of `onStart`